# Implementation of LinkedList C++ using friend

Tags: c++, object-oriented, linked-list

I am implementing my own linkedlist in C++ as part of a class assignment. My main concern isn't with the style of the code nor the pros/cons of including or not including certain features as I am still developing member functions.

I would mainly like to know if my approach of declaring `LinkedList` as a `friend` of `Node` is reasonable. My decision for doing this comes from the fact that there is absolutely no need for anything to access my `Node` class besides `LinkedList` (e.g. I don't want to be able to create a `Node` object in main). When I do this, however, I find myself no longer needing `public` and `private` access modifiers for `Node`. Furthermore, I don't particularly need getter/setter methods as I can just access `Node`'s member variables directly from `LinkedList` (you can see below that I don't call `Node::getVal()` or `Node::getNext()` once).

Coming from the world of Java, it seems really strange to ever access an object's internal data directly without getters/setters. What do you guys think? Does this `friend` relation make sense?

```
template <typename T> class Node
{
    friend class LinkedList<T>;
    // private:
        Node<T>* next;  // CAN ACCESS MEMBERS DIRECTLY BECAUSE OF FRIEND DECLARATION
        T value;
    // public:
        Node<T>(T valuep)
        {
            value = valuep;
            next = NULL;
        }
        void insert(T valuep)
        {
            if(next == NULL)
            {
                next = new Node<T>(valuep);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                next->insert(valuep);
            }
        }

        T getVal() // DON'T NEED BECAUSE OF FRIEND DECLARATION
        {
            return value;
        }
        Node<T>* getNext() // DON'T NEED BECAUSE OF FRIEND DECLARATION
        {
            return next;
        }
};

template <typename T> class LinkedList
{
    private:
        Node<T>* head;
    public:
        LinkedList<T>()
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
        ~LinkedList<T>()
        {
            Node<T>* currentNode = head;
            while(currentNode!=NULL)
            {
                Node<T>* next = currentNode->next;
                delete currentNode;
                currentNode = next;
            }
        }
        void insert(T valuep)
        {
            if (head == NULL)
            {
                head = new Node<T>(valuep);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                head->insert(valuep);
            }
        }

        void print()
        {
            Node<T>* temp = head;
            while(temp!=NULL)
            {
               std::cout << temp->value << std::endl; // ACCESS Node's MEMBERS DIRECTLY
               temp = temp->next; // ACCESS Node's MEMBERS DIRECTLY
            }
        }

        void update(int indexp, T valuep)
        {
            if(indexp==0)
            {
                head->value = valuep; // ACCESS Node's MEMBERS DIRECTLY
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: While you are free to call attention to specific areas (performance, formatting, etc), the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states that any aspect of the code posted is fair game for feedback and criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
template<typename T> class LinkedList {

    struct LinkedListNode {
        T m_element;
        LinkedListNode* m_next;

        LinkedListNode(T element)
        :
        m_element{element},
        m_next{nullptr}
        {}
    };

public:

    LinkedList()
    :
    m_head{nullptr},
    m_tail{nullptr}
    {}

    void add(T element) {
        LinkedListNode* node = new LinkedListNode(element);
    }

private:
    LinkedListNode* m_head;
    LinkedListNode* m_tail;
};

int main() {
    LinkedList<int> l;
}
```

That way, your `LinkedListNode` implementation is not available outside of your `LinkedList`.

Comment: Declaring things in the smallest possible scope. Excellent.

Comment: @Vorac I am not quite sure how to interpret your comment. Sarcasm vs. not sarcasm?

Comment: Could someone please elaborate on the use of `nullptr` in this case instead of `NULL`? To the best of my understanding, somehow nullptr unambiguously represents both zero and null? Why would simply `NULL` be ambiguous?

Comment: @SuperGoA All I know is that `nullptr` was introduced in C++11. Once again, all I know is that `NULL` is defined in some header file (possibly `cstdlib`). If you use a modern C++ compiler, throw away `NULL`s and rely on `nullptr`s.

Comment: @coderodde sorry, I forgot you can not see who upvoted the post. Not sarcasm. I value highly minimum visibility and it's brother shortest lifetime(enabling efficinet RAII).

Answer (score 1):

> I would mainly like to know if my approach of declaring `LinkedList` as a `friend` of `Node` is reasonable.

Who needs to know about `Node`s existence?  In this context, `Node` is purely an implementation detail of the `LinkedList` structure.  Users do not need to know that `Node` exists, so like any good <strike>spy</strike> engineer, only expose information to <strike>collaborators</strike> users on a *need-to-know* basis.  Make `Node` a `private` nested class of `LinkedList`.

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList 
{
    struct Node               // No public exposure, only friends and
    {                         // nested classes of LinkedList know details.
        T value;              // Get/Set directly or enable access control.
        Node* next{nullptr};
    };
    Node* head;

    /* ... */
};
```

---

```
    friend class LinkedList<T>;
```

If you are using a pre-[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) compiler, you will need to forward declare your `LinkedList<T>`.

---

```
    Node<T>(T valuep)
    {
        value = valuep;
        next = NULL;
    }
```

Prefer in-class initializers ([c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)) for initializing constants.  Prefer member initializers instead of assignment.

For parameters that are known and cheap to copy (integrals, floating points, pointers, references), you can't really beat passing by value.  When working with anything else larger than 2-3 bytes or if working with templates, prefer to pass by reference (to `const` for in-only params).

With [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), prefer `nullptr` to `NULL`.  `nullptr` is now a well-specified (and restrictive) null type (`std::nullptr_t`) instead of macro representing an integer.

```
template <typename T> 
class Node
{
    Node<T>* next{nullptr};                     // in-class initialization
    T value;
public:
    Node<T>(T const& valuep) : value{valuep} {} // member initialization
};
```

---

`else` isn't needed after using a control flow interrupt (`return`, `break`, `continue`, etc).  Help reduce indentation and limit the amount of code you ask readers to keep track of.

```
        if (head == nullptr)
        {
            head = new Node<T>(valuep);
            return;
        }
        head->insert(valuep);
```

---

`getVal` returns copies.  Have you considered returning [`const`-]references?  Consider providing `const` on member functions that do not mutate.  See [`const`-correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).

---

Try to be descriptive with your naming.  I shouldn't have to look through documentation, comments, or code to know that this is a Forward/Singly-Linked list.

---

Follow the [Rule of Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  If you define one of the special member functions (destructor, copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment operator), then explicitly define them all.

With in-class initializers, prefer letting the compiler implicitly generate a default constructor.  If you require an explicit argument constructor or a conversion constructor, explicitly default the default constructor.

Your destructor could save on one pointer copy by using `head` directly instead of `currentNode`.

```
template <typename T>
struct LinkedList {
  private:
    struct Node { T value; Node* next; };
    Node* head{nullptr};
  public:
    // Rule of three
    LinkedList(LinkedList const& that) { /* copy that */ }
    LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList const& that) { /* copy that */ }
    ~LinkedList() { /* destroy this */ }

    // Rule of five - C++11
    LinkedList(LinkedList&& that) { /* move that */ }
    LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList&& that) { /* move that */ }
}
```

---

Do you always want to print to `std::cout`?  Consider defining a `std::ostream&` parameter to take from the caller.  Even better, provide an iterator interface and let the user access all or part of the list values.

Be aware of what `std::endl` does.  If you just want a new line, prefer streaming the new-line character (`'\n'`).  If you want to express to the reader you intended to flush a buffered stream, explicitly stream `std::flush`.

---

`update` is incomplete as it doesn't handle non-zero indices.  If it's not ready to be reviewed, don't include it for code review.

---

Insertions at the back of the list are expensive.  Consider a constant time approach by bookkeeping and inserting directly at the tail.

Answer (score 1):

#### No, it cannot be reasonable for a Node to be a `friend` of the List

... even without looking at your code: For a Node within a Linked List be a friend of the Linked List structure/class implies the Node has members which act upon the containing Linked List structure. That should not happen: Other than in exceptional circumstances (which yours aren't), local, internal structures/classes within a larger data structure should be passive, acted *upopn* by that structure's methods (or by free-standing functions involving the outer and inner structures).